# How to make button press limit time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want a code when I pressing the button Then the button is Impossible to click

again for 24 hours and after the 24 the button available again.

Comment: Have you tried making it impossible to click for 5 seconds? This would be easier to develop at first.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Additional important information is presented in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What is your context? Is this a web thing? An app which is always on? A form which will be opened and closed randomly? Something which is database related? There are many different answers depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

When button is clicked disable button and start a timer (timer should have 24h interval) when it ticks, enable button and stop the timer.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the above comments, there are many ways to do this depending on your need. Below is just a simple example that should help.

```
Private ButtonTimer As New Timer
Private ButtonCountDown As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Disable Button
    Button1.Enabled = False

    'Set Countdown
    ButtonCountDown = 24

    'Setup Timer
    AddHandler ButtonTimer.Tick, AddressOf ButtonTimer_Tick
    ButtonTimer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 'Every 1 Hour
    ButtonTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonTimer_Tick(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'Decrement ButtonCountDown and if not zero we can just leave and do nothing.
    ButtonCountDown -= 1
    If Not ButtonCountDown = 0 Then Exit Sub

    'We have reached zero, stop timer and clean up.
    ButtonTimer.Stop()
    RemoveHandler ButtonTimer.Tick, AddressOf ButtonTimer_Tick
    ButtonTimer.Dispose()

    'Enable Button
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

These are the important lines:

```
ButtonCountDown = 24
ButtonTimer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 'Every 1 Hour
```

The above example will check the timer every hour and countdown from 24, thus 24 hours.

For testing purposes, change to minutes:

```
ButtonCountDown = 2
ButtonTimer.Interval = 1000 * 60 'Every 1 Minute
```

Now the button will disable for 2 minutes (timer checks every minute).

For testing purposes, change to seconds:

```
ButtonCountDown = 20
ButtonTimer.Interval = 1000 'Every 1 Second
```

Now the button will disable for 20 seconds (timer checks every second).